# Toggle between Text box and Drop Down based on a value of a field using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Based on the value of a field, we need to populate either a text box or a drop-down in md table.
The value in the field will be either blank or be with options.
For a row in the table, when the field is blank then show up the text box in the front end else when it is not blank - Get the drop down. How do we use if condition while calling md table to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide some code, tell us what you tried, what is failing.

Comment: also a mockup image/html would help as well